# Android sdk manager doesn't recognize installed packages

Tags: android, macos

I'm attempting to update the Android SDK via command line on a Mac OSX 10.11.6.  Something that I've done hundreds of times, but now the SDK is stuck downloading the same package over and over!  Anyone else seeing this?  I'm accepting the license, it's just not registering!

Here's the bit...

```
November 20, 2015

Do you accept the license 'android-sdk-license-c81a61d9' [y/n]: y

Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Downloading Android Support Repository, revision 39
  Installing Android Support Repository, revision 39
    Installed Android Support Repository, revision 3999%)
  Done. 1 package installed.
minimac:android dannyd$ android update sdk --no-ui
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
  Validate XML
  Parse XML
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  ...
  ...
  ...
November 20, 2015
Do you accept the license 'android-sdk-license-c81a61d9' [y/n]:
```

If I repeat the same command, it wants to install the same package again!  It's already there.  The license ID is even the same!  I've already gone so far as to clear the SDK directory completely and start reinstalling from scratch...no luck.

Comment: Have you tried out  apt-get update before installing the android sdk via terminal?

Comment: Don't think that 'apt-get' is available on OS X...  did do a 'brew update' though, even though Android sdk isn't provided through that.

Comment: same problem here but on Ubuntu

Comment: Alright... I'm getting this same response on multiple different hosts now; When running with the regular UI, everything shows installed... when from command line, I get the same error.

Think it's an issue with how their command line processing is being done.